# Need to print UWP MapControl with route results

Tags: printing, routes, uwp

I have a MapControl working just creating my route. Now, I just need to figure out a way to print it out. Using the UWP printing sample, I get a black box where the control should be. The map and route are being built, just not rendered correctly in the print preview. I thought I saw a MapControl.Print... but I think that was in the Bing.Maps stuff. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the UWP printing sample, I get a black box where the control should be.

It seems the MapControl can not be printed.

As a workround, we can use [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) to get the image from the `MapControl`. That we can print the image.

> Using a RenderTargetBitmap, you can accomplish scenarios such as applying image effects to a visual that originally came from a XAML UI composition, generating thumbnail images of child pages for a navigation system, or enabling the user to save parts of the UI as an image source and then share that image with other apps.
>
> Because RenderTargetBitmap is a subclass of ImageSource, it can be used as the image source for Image elements or an ImageBrush brush.

For more info,see [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx).

For example:

```cs
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(MyMap);
MyImage.Source = renderTargetBitmap;
```

The printing code:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private PrintManager printmgr = PrintManager.GetForCurrentView();
    private PrintDocument printDoc = null;
    private PrintTask task = null;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        printmgr.PrintTaskRequested += Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested;
    }

    private void Printmgr_PrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        task = args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Print", OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested);
        task.Completed += PrintTask_Completed;
        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private void PrintTask_Completed(PrintTask sender, PrintTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        //the PrintTask is completed
    }

    private async void OnPrintTaskSourceRequrested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
    {
        var def = args.GetDeferral();
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
          () =>
          {
              args.SetSource(printDoc?.DocumentSource);
          });
        def.Complete();
    }

    private async void appbar_Printer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (printDoc != null)
        {
            printDoc.GetPreviewPage -= OnGetPreviewPage;
            printDoc.Paginate -= PrintDic_Paginate;
            printDoc.AddPages -= PrintDic_AddPages;
        }
        this.printDoc = new PrintDocument();

        printDoc.GetPreviewPage += OnGetPreviewPage;

        printDoc.Paginate += PrintDic_Paginate;

        printDoc.AddPages += PrintDic_AddPages;

        bool showPrint = await PrintManager.ShowPrintUIAsync();
    }

    private void PrintDic_AddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {
        printDoc.AddPage(this);

        printDoc.AddPagesComplete();
    }

    private void PrintDic_Paginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintTaskOptions opt = task.Options;

        printDoc.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);
    }

    private void OnGetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        printDoc.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I have the RenderTargetBitmap from the MapControl, but can't seem to print. I can view the bitmap in an onscreen control, but when I try and print it is usually a solid color (not the same color each time). If I render the bitmap on the screen, I can see it, but in the print preview it is strangely blank. Not getting any errors I can see in terms of binding, etc.

Comment: The RenderTargetBitmap need to wait the mapcontrol to be loaded, if the mapcontrol is not loaded it may has the strangely blank.

Comment: Not sure why this is necessary, but I got it all to work by saving the RenderTargetBitmap as a jpg image in the temp directory. I then bind to that file in my XAML and the printout works fine.